# Nightwatch .element() always using last value in array

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a nightwatch test where I am testing a list of urls for mobile app content RSS, CSS, and HTML 'feeds'. They are in arrays like:

```
var rssFeeds = [
'https://www.example.com/rss/feed1',
'https://www.example.com/rss/feed2',
]
```

In my test, I am using a for loop to iterate through each url in the array to test like:

```
var urlToTest = ''; //< -- this is always 'https://www.example.com/rss/feed2' in .element check below
    // rss Feeds
    for (var i = 0; i < rssFeeds.length; i++) {
        urlToTest = rssFeeds[i].toString()
        browser
            .url('https://validator.w3.org/feed/')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 'W3C RSS Validator page loaded... https://validator.w3.org/feed/ \n')
            .setValue('#url', urlToTest)
            .click('a[class="submit"]')
            .element('css selector', 'img[title="Valid RSS"]', function (result) {
                if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
                    // Element is present, do the appropriate tests
                    console.log('valid RSS...')
                    browser.perform(function () {
                        browser.verify.ok(1 == 1, urlToTest + ' valid RSS...') //<-- HERE
                    })
                } else {
                    // Element is not present.
                    console.log('invalid RSS...')
                    browser.verify.ok(1 != 1, urlToTest + ' invalid RSS...') //<-- AND HERE
                }
            })
    }
```

In each `.url()` call, it is properly entering feed1, feed2, etc sequentially, however, in the `.element()` call it is always the last value in the array, so the reporting looks wrong. It always looks like:

> ✓ appContent
>
> TC004-AppContent
>
> ✓ W3C RSS Validator page loaded... https://validator.w3.org/feed/
>
> ✓ Passed [ok]: https://www.example.com/rss/feed2 valid RSS...
>
> ✓ W3C RSS Validator page loaded... https://validator.w3.org/feed/
>
> ✓ Passed [ok]: https://www.example.com/rss/feed2 valid RSS..

So, since `urlToTest` is **always** the last array value, the report isn't very helpful right now by not differentiating what url is good/bad.
I tried wrapping different parts of the code in `perform()` call to try to get it to run exactly when it needs too to no avail.

I also saw posts on `.execute()` but I am just not getting it...

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to move the `.element()` call into a function outside the loop as per a javascript issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549514/nightwatch-execute-command-within-for-loop-runs-out-of-order)

So, the code is now:

```
var urlToTest = '';
    // rss Feeds
    for (var i = 0; i < rssFeeds.length; i++) {
        urlToTest = rssFeeds[i].toString()
        browser
            .url('https://validator.w3.org/feed/')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 'W3C RSS Validator page loaded... https://validator.w3.org/feed/')
            .setValue('#url', urlToTest)
            .click('a[class="submit"]')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 'W3C results page loaded...')
        checkElement(browser, 'img[title="Valid RSS"]', urlToTest)
    }
```

and

```
// must call from outside loop in order to maintain proper syncronous execution
function checkElement(browser, elem, url) {
    browser.element('css selector', elem, function (result) {
        if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
            // Element is present, do the appropriate tests
            browser.verify.ok(1 == 1, url + ' valid feed...')
        } else {
            // Element is not present.
            browser.verify.ok(1 != 1, url + ' invalid feed...')
        }
    })
}
```